# MVC Data Validation only insert form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working with MVC5. I have a Model call `User` that have several properties. Some of them, like `Password` and `ConfirmPassword` are required.

It looks like this.

```
public partial class Users
{
    public long User_id { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public string Password { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] // Does not effect with database
     [Compare("Password")]
    public virtual string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

The View Inherit from a Model that looks like this.

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public Users user { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCountries { get; set; }
}
```

When I Update the user. I do not render the Password and the ConfirmPassoword.

My Update Mehtod is like this.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Update(UserViewModel model)
{
     ModelState.Remove("Password");
     ModelState.Remove("ConfirmPassword");
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
     }
}
```

I wanted to disabled validation, so, as it is said in severals sites, I add in the controller the following

> ModelState.Remove

But when I asked for ModelState.IsValid it is always false...

It happens because Data Validation is in `Users` Class and I inherit from `UserViewModel`?

Why it does not work?

My View is here

```html
@model TableAvivaVoz.Models.UserViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";

}

<h2>Editar</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Users</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.user.User_id)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Country_id, "Country", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.user.Country_id, Model.AvailableCountries, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Country_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Nombre" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Apellido" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Sex, "Género", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Label("Hombre")
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.user.Sex, "1", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.Label("Mujer")
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.user.Sex, "0", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Sex, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.CodArea, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.CodArea, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Cód Area" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.CodArea, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Número Telefono" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="form-group">
            <div style="position:relative;">
                <label>Image</label>
                <div>Upload new image: <input type="file" name="Image" /></div>
            </div>
            @if (Model.user == null || Model.user.Picture == null)
            {
                <div class="form-control-static">No Image</div>
            }
            else
                {
                   <img class="img-thumbnail" width="100" height="100" src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.user.Picture)"  />
                }
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
       

    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what is your question here??????

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: I completed just now, I had errors in my code so I could not submitted correctly. thanks

Comment: You need separate view models for 'Registering' and 'Editng' users. And view models should never contain properties which are data models.

Comment: My Users class in created by Entity Framework when I bind the Database...

Comment: @diego you use data annotations in User do not use in UserViewModel And Add Your Razor Code

Comment: My Validation is in User. Class.. the View inherit from UserViewModel

Comment: Password not exist in your Viewmodel , while you  use it

Comment: I hope you do understand what I mean  @Diego

Answer (score 0):

Do Not Add Data Annotations In Your  Entity . You must add Data Annotations in Your ViewModel so that View is Strongly Type Of User ViewModel .

Mode
state consider UserViwMode

So You Must remove `public Users user { get; set; }` in UserViewModel and Add this Change :

```
public class UserViewModel
{
  puclic string Name { get; set; }

  puclic string LastName { get; set; }

  puclic bool sex { get; set; }

  // and more ...

  public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCountries { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: OK Soheil... If UserViewModel Inherit from Users Entity... How can I add data Annotations in UserViewModel from Users properties ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, as it said Stephen. I duplicate the User Entity and UserModel and Map those Model with Mapper. as this 
[example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2010/12/07/view-model-versus-domain-entity-validation-with-mvc/)